# are these two asyncrounous functions indentical?

Tags: dart

I have a function defined by:

```
static Future<http.Response> checkToken(token) async {
    return await http.post("my-url", headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }, body: json.encode({
        "token": token
    })).timeout(const Duration (seconds:5), onTimeout : () => null);
}
```

I wonder if this function is identical to this function:

```
static Future<http.Response> checkToken(token) {
    return http.post("my-url", headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }, body: json.encode({
        "token": token
    })).timeout(const Duration (seconds:5), onTimeout : () => null);
}
```

In the second definition I removed `async / await` part, cause on the web I found this statement:

> Tip: If a function returns a Future, it’s considered asyncrounous; you do not need to mark the body of this function with async keyword. The async keyword is necessary only if you have used the await keyword in the body of your function.

Are these two functions identical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your asynchronously method does not contain the keyword `await`, then the two methods is indeed identical.

Answer (score 3):

It's true that the `async` keyword is *not* what makes a function asynchronous.  The two versions of your function therefore are both asynchronous, and they're mostly equivalent but are subtly *not* identical.

The first version (which uses `await`) waits for a `Future` to complete and returns a *new* `Future`.  The second version just returns the original `Future` directly.

Let's simplify the example:

```dart
final someFuture = Future.value(42);

Future<int> returnsFuture() => someFuture;

Future<int> awaitsFuture() async => await someFuture;

void main() {
  final same = identical(returnsFuture(), awaitsFuture());
  print('Identical Futures: $same'); // Prints: Identical Futures: false
}
```

In practice this usually shouldn't matter.  Two cases where it might are:

- Your code is somehow sensitive to specific `Future` instances.
- `await` always yields, so the extra `await` could very slightly delay execution.